# gdb doesn't exist or is not executable in Free Pascal

Tags: gdb, lazarus, freepascal

I've installed lazarus and Free Pascal. Everything is ok. But when i run an empty project i get: `The debugger "/usr/bin/gdb" does not exist or is not executable. See Tools->Options->Debugger options`. I'm going mad, don't know how to fix it. Plz somebody help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with Free Pascal, but I'm having trouble understanding why this is an issue. Do you see the same behavior when you try to run the compiler with a populated project? I suspect that an empty project doesn't have the compiler paths filled out, but properly setting up a project and actually giving it both correct paths and something to compile should resolve this.

Comment: Lazarus is a FPC specific IDE, so the compiler settings are global, and typically not per project

Answer (score 1):

GDB is the GNU debugger, and is an external dependency. Make sure GDB is installed and at /usr/lib/gdb or adjust the setting appropriately

Comment: I code sign GDB like this [link](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/). In Debugger IDE Options I set path GNU debugger(gdb) as /usr/local/bin/gdb. But nothing ! I got the same error: please check gdb is code signed - see taskgated(8). What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry,  I can follow generic *nix, but working around the things that Apple does to make independent development more difficult is beyond me.